# Recrear solicitud de postman en Solicitud Guzzle

Tags: laravel, api, rest, postman, guzzle

[image: IMAGEN 1]
[image: IMAGEN 2]

Tengo una solicitud vía Api rest en Postman que funciona perfectamente. El problema es que cuando intento hacer dicha solicitud por Guzzle  el api me responde con un error que indica Estructura General no valida, El error es muy poco descriptivo y no se que estoy haciendo mal a la hora de armar la solicitud. Estoy seguro que el json no es porque copio el json que envió en la solicitud por Guzzle y lo pego en postman y también funciona. Me justaría saber que tiene de diferente mi código con el ejemplo en postman

```
  $cliente = new GuzzleHttp\Client(); 
          $resp = $cliente->post('https://wsechomo.itau.com.ar/apiCvu/v1/'.$metodo.'/', 
      ['cert' => [__DIR__.'/CAcerts/itau.pem','Itewewwew']],
          ['headers' => 
             [ 'cuitPsp'             => '3023233'], 
             [ 'keyValidationToken' => ''], 
             [ 'Content-Type'        => 'application/json'], 
            
             [
                'json' => $JSON
             ]
          ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

No hay un orden en la estructura de tu Guzzle. Es mejor tomarse un poco más de tiempo y optar por una mayor legibilidad para que así sea más sencillo darse cuenta de los posibles errores.

```
$cliente->post("https://wsechomo.itau.com.ar/apiCvu/v1/{$metodo}/", [
    'cert' => [__DIR__.'/CAcerts/itau.pem','Itewewwew'],
    'headers' => [
        'cuitPsp'            => '3023233',
        'keyValidationToken' => '',
        'Accept'             => 'application/json'
    ],
    'body' => $json
]);
```

Como podrás notar, sólo debe existir un parámetro (`array`) que tendrá los `subarrays` de `headers`, `cert` y `body`. En resumen debería quedarte algo así:

```
$cliente->post("..", [array]);
```

**Tu error:**

Pero tú estás enviando más de un array, así:

```
$cliente->post("..", [array], [array], [array]);
```